# Media player with history for windows

Tags: windows, windows-media-player

I need a media player which shows all music files which I have listened and how much times it is played. As I know Windows Media Player hasn't such functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You Windows Media Player can have this feature if you will download Last.fm music tracker from this website: http://www.last.fm/download and then after installation it will automatically offer you to add plugin for your Windows Media Player and in couple of minutes you can build your own music profile :]

Example: http://www.last.fm/user/San-Tus

Answer (score 2):

[Foobar](http://www.foobar2000.org/) with Playback Statistics component can do this

- download & install foobar2000 (I recommend portable mode)
- add your music folders to foobar's [media library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TspS2.png)
  `menu → file → preferences → media library → add`
- download & install [Playback Statistics](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_playcount)
  `menu → file → preferences → components → install`
  **Note:** Played files are only counted AFTER the installation of this component.
  Play some music files before you proceed with the next step or you will get an empty list
- create a new autoplaylist which shows only played music files
  `menu → library → search`
- Insert this [query](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Query_syntax) `NOT %play_count% MISSING SORT DESCENDING BY %play_count%`
- click on the <kbd>...</kbd> button and create the autoplaylist

  [image]

---

You can adjust the layout of your playlist in every way you can imagine.
Just ask what you want here or over there at [Hydrogenaudio](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showforum=27)

- Here is an example of my autoplaylists which uses a dynamic auto rating
  (e.g. 2 times played last week is higher than 5 times played last year)

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

WMP does in fact have such functionality. Create an auto playlist, enter a name for the playlist, and under **Music in my library** add the following criteria:

```
Play count: Total overall Is Greater Than 0
```

Then click **OK** to save the playlist.

As for showing the play counts, right-click a column header in the library (such as **Title**), select **Choose columns**, tick the **Play count** item, make sure that **Hide columns automatically** is unchecked, and click **OK**.